# How to make functions work with Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

functions/index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const db = admin.database().ref()
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // do whatever here...
  db.child('something').once('value').then(snap => console.log(snap.key))
})
```

Above works for Firebase.

I'm interested in making [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) example work from functions. Something like this but working:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const db = admin.database().ref()

exports.request = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  let docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF")      
  docRef.get().then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) console.log("Document data:", doc.data())
      else console.log("No such document!")
  }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error)
  })

})
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `admin.firestore()` instead of `admin.database()`. Be sure your firebase-admin module is 5.4.1 or better.

```
exports.fun = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const store = admin.firestore()
    store.collection('users').doc('foo').get().then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log(doc.data())
            res.send(doc.data())
        }
        else {
            res.send("Nothing")
        }
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason)
        res.send(reason)
    })
})
```

Comment: `firebase-admin module is 5.4.1 or better` was the missing key.  I had to manually update the package.json then run `npm i`. Works now, thanks.

Comment: If it isn't too much to ask, can you provide steps to reproduce the update/fix?

Comment: Go to functions directory and update `package.json` file. Under `dependencies` I have this currently: `"firebase-admin": "~5.4.1", "firebase-functions": "^0.7.0"`. Then open command prompt if on windows, navigate to your functions directory and run `npm install`.

Comment: @doug-stevenson can you clarify on the location of the docs for that?

Comment: tried this code, it was giving this error.  `Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return`

Comment: @essramos That's not an error, that's a lint check. You can fix it by adding a return value of `Promise.resolve("Finished")`