# Read data from Firebase in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am building a chatbot but I got stuck fetching data from **Firebase** from **Dialogflow**.

I want a user to input his name, the bot to query Firebase and check if the name exists. If it does **"user exists"** else **"user n not in the database"**.

[this is the code am using presently][1]

```
function SaveName(agent){
const number = agent.parameters.number;  // when I input the number in Fialogflow
const docRef = db.collection('names').doc(sessionId);

return docRef.get()
  .then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
      agent.add('No data found in the database!');
      console.log(doc);
    } else {
      agent.add(doc.data().orders);
    }
    return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
  }).catch(() => {
    agent.add('Error reading entry from the Firestore database.');
    agent.add('Please add a entry to the database first by saying, "Write <your phrase> to the database"');
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by [configuring the fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-configure) for your agent.

1. Go to **Intents**, select your intent and then scroll down to the fulfillment section.
2. Click on *Enable webhook call for this intent* (see [Custom webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-configure#custom_webhook)).
3. Create the webhook (you can enable the [inline editor](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-configure#create_a_webhook_with_the_inline_editor) at **Fulfillment** - Inline Editor to do so).
4. In your webhook, query Firestore (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46568084/4658957)).

Note that anyone will be able to know if a user exists or not in your db. 
If you are building for the Google Assistant, have a look at [account linking](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity).

Comment: it did not work, but can u reffer to my code and see my mistake        function SaveName (agent){
  store.collection('names').doc('value').get().then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log(doc.data());
            res.send(doc.data());
        }
        else {
            res.send("Nothing");
        }
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason);
        res.send(reason);
    });

}

Comment: Can you include your code in the question using the code sample tool rather than linking a screenshot? It'll make it easier to help you!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing some similar issue where the fetched details were not being shown in the agent interaction. This happened with the template given [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs) too. I then just **removed the responses from the ReadFromFirestore Intent** and was getting the expected fetched queries back. I again tried by putting the response back and calling the intent and the response was sort of alternating between the default response and the firestore query response. 
Still, not keeping it worked for me and thought would help others too.